# MSVC 2008 16 Bytes structure members alignment weirdness

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, alignment

Can anybody please explain what's going on?

My **MSVC 2008** project's **structure member alignment** setting is set to **16 bytes** (/Zp16) alignment, however one of the following structures is being aligned by **16 bytes** and another is aligned only by **8 bytes**... **WHY?!!!**

```
struct HashData
{
    void *pData;
    const char* pName;
    int crc;
    bool bModified;
}; // sizeof (HashData) == 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 + padding = 16 bytes, ok

class StringHash
{
    HashData data[1024];
    int mask;
    int size;
}; // sizeof(StringHash) == 1024 * 16 + 4 + 4 + 0 = 16392 bytes, why not 16400 bytes?
```

This may not look like a big deal, but it's a big problem for me, since I am forced to emulate the **MSVC** structures alignment in **GCC** and specifying the **aligned(16)** attribute makes the **sizeof (StringHash) == 16400**!

Please tell me, when and why **MSVC** overrides the **/Zp16** setting, I absolutely can't fathom it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the `/Zp16` option.

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx),

> When you specify this option, each structure member after the first is
>   stored on either the size of the member type or n-byte boundaries
>   (where n is 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16), **whichever is smaller.**

Please read the "whichever is smaller".  It doesn't say that the struct will be padded by `16`. It rather defines the boundary of each member relative to each other, starting from the first member.

What you basically want is [align (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx) attribute, which says

> Use __declspec(align(#)) to precisely control the alignment of user-defined data

So try this:

```
_declspec(align(16)) struct StringHash
{
    HashData data[1024];
    int mask;
    int size;
}; 

std::cout << sizeof(StringHash) << std::endl;
```

It should print what you expect.

Or you can use [#pragma pack(16)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 Also OP, if you want to do something similar to `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` in MSVC it's `#pragma pack(push, 16)` `struct /* ... */` `#pragma pack(pop)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the pack pragma directive:

```
// Set packing to 16 byte alignment
#pragma pack(16)

struct HashData
{
    void *pData;
    const char* pName;
    int crc;
    bool bModified;
};

class StringHash
{
    HashData data[1024];
    int mask;
    int size;
};

// Restore default packing
#pragma pack()
```

See: [pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Working with Packing Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253935%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)